# When I compile a kotlin native project I get "Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.konan.env.env", why?

Tags: kotlin, native

I create a kotlin native app from scratch and I get the error above. How can I fix this?
It's a simple "Hello World" app. I have other computers and this error does not appear there.
I think it has to do with Konan not downloading its files??
Any ideas?

Normally the project should compile and run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Culprit: windows path variable.
My Windows path variable had an illegal character. This prevented the Konan download. I fixed the path variable and now it's working smoothly.